# What should I add to the soil to make my hydrangeas blue?

Tags: soil, soil-amendment

I am about to plant some new hydrangeas. What should I use to amend the soil with to make the hydrangeas blue?

Comment: Which variety of Hydrangea - macrophylla (mophead/round flowers) or paniculata (cone shaped flowers) and what colour is it now?

Comment: Related, or possible duplicate: [How do I change the color of my hydrangea flowers](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/1744/how-do-i-change-the-color-of-my-hydrangea-flowers?)

Comment: Welcome Peggy! In addition to the excellent answer from andrewbuilder, would you please have a look at the question I linked above and see if it helps you with what you need?

Comment: Where are these hydrangeas planted?  If they are near a concrete foundation or concrete walkway you will have a tough time keeping the pH acidic.

Answer (score 4):

To obtain a blue flowering hydrangea, the soil around the roots of the plant must contain aluminium.

For this aluminium to be available as a nutrient, the pH of the soil must be very low / acidic (around 4.5-5.5).

Note that an acidic soil may be detrimental to the growth of surrounding plants that may prefer a more neutral soil pH. It is therefore sensible to group acid loving plants together.

When added to the soil, *aluminium sulphate* can serve to provide a source of aluminium and create a more acidic soil. Aluminium sulfate is a water soluble chemical compound with the formula Al  <sub>2</sub> (SO  <sub>4</sub> )  <sub>3</sub> .

Creating suitable soil chemistry with aluminium sulphate may be a process that takes two or three or more years to achieve success.

Additionally, there are some important considerations:

- aluminium sulphate used as an agricultural soil amendment, has the potential at stronger doses to burn the roots of young plants;
- A fertiliser low in phosphorus and high in potassium is helpful in producing a strong blue color (superphosphates and bone meal should be avoided when trying to produce blue);
- Rich compost will contribute to creating an acidic soil, however once the compost has broken down the immediate effects are significantly reduced.

Comment: I thought I had already commented a moment ago so if there are two comments, that is why.  Andrew, this is a fabulous answer.  I also said something to the effect that decomposed organic matter BUFFERS the pH of the soil; making acidic soils less acidic, alkaline soils less alkaline.  Nice answer...!